# Adding script via wordpress wp_enqueue_scripts in the <head>

Tags: wordpress, dom

When adding js file via wp_enqueue_scripts it's placed it in the `<head>` tag in the html source.

But in the DOM (F12) it's placed in the `<body>`.
What can be the reason?

This is my page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PAGE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" id="query-monitor-css"  href="https://www.sukkah2go.kipa.co.il/wp-content/plugins/query-monitor/assets/query-monitor.css?ver=1478770264" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" id="font-awesome-css"  href="https://www.sukkah2go.kipa.co.il/wp-content/plugins/wipi-builder/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.6.3" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" id="mono-social-icons-css"  href="https://www.sukkah2go.kipa.co.il/wp-content/themes/wipi/css/mono-social-icons.css?ver=1.2.1" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" id="hebrew-fonts-css"  href="https://www.sukkah2go.kipa.co.il/wp-content/themes/wipi/css/hebrew-fonts.css?ver=1.2.1" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" id="jquery-magnificpopup-css"  href="https://www.sukkah2go.kipa.co.il/wp-content/plugins/wipi-builder/css/jquery.magnificpopup.css?ver=1.2.1" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" id="wipi-css"  href="https://www.sukkah2go.kipa.co.il/wp-content/uploads/wipi/skin-57f534186c4d2.css?ver=4.6.1" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" id="wipi-rtl-css"  href="https://www.sukkah2go.kipa.co.il/wp-content/themes/wipi/css/rtl.css?ver=4.6.1" type="text/css" media="all" />
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it's probably invalid HTML. When you do view source, you get the raw HTML from the server. When you use your dev tools (F12), you get output that is parsed by your browser and it will try to fix any problems with the HTML.

Comment: I recommend using a validator to validate your theme's raw html to find the problem. You can use this: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: For wordpress I think you should have `<?php wp_head(); ?>` inside your `<head>` section. That is how `wp_enqueue_scripts` works. Do you have this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at code reference: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

as you can see, last param of boolean type, and if set to true, it will output script file in body of document, not in head. Maybe that is problem.

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = false, array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```